# XNA 2D Game Engines

Tags: xna, 2d

I am just getting back into game development and I am really impressed with XNA. My only problem is that I want a *free* community based 2d game engine so that I can harness the power of the community. **Does anybody know of a good XNA 2d game engine that is currently being supported or Do I just have to write one myself?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the engines posted are pretty much your only options for 2D right now.  You can find a list of available game engines for XNA at the [XNA forums](http://forums.xna.com/forums/t/12882.aspx).  You could also check out [DEngine](http://dengine.codeplex.com/), but it looks like that is still in an alpha stage.

For certain types of games (e.g. tile-based RPG) there are starter kits, such as the [RPG starter kit](http://creators.xna.com/en-US/starterkit/roleplayinggame) and [spaceship game starter kit](http://creators.xna.com/en-US/starterkit/netrumble).  If you happen to be developing a game for one of those genres, you could build on those examples.

Comment: I've looked at all those that you suggested but they seemed geared directly to their particular genre. I guess I'm looking for a EntLib for XNA but I guess it doesn't exist. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

FlatRedBall is a good option and is being actively supported. http://www.flatredball.com/frb/

Comment: I looked at FlatRedBall and it is missing something. I can't tell what it is, but dare I say... it's not a very sexy engine. Thanks though.

Comment: The quality of an engine is how it works behind the scenes, not the models and textures used to showcase it... You can probably make it as 'sexy' as you want with a little effort.

Answer (score 4):

[Ice Cream](http://icecream.epsicode.net/)  is really freaking sweet but last I check still in beta. So its a little bit buggy but, I'm sure once they get an official release going. Its already pretty awesome and pretty damn usable. And it comes with Milkshake , a level / animation editor (So Sweet!)

Comment: I can't find the license for that engine, I'm interested in it

Comment: I would recommend just going to the IRC chat room and asking. I couldn't find it on the site either. I would imagine its with the install but I haven't taken a look at it in a while so maybe check there too.

Answer (score 3):

[TorqueX 2D](http://www.garagegames.com/products/torquex-2d) from GarageGames

Comment: well I meant XNA based and that doesn't cost money. I've used Torque engines before but they lack documentation. Thanks

Comment: Ah. You might want to clarify that in the question (I didn't immediately think of that when I read "community based")

Answer (score 1):

The Kitae game engine is currently under heavy development @ [NullCity.com](http://kitae.nullcity.com/)

It is currently in beta but you can sign up for testing.

Answer (score 1):

Synapse Gaming's SunBurn has a really active community, and it meets all your other criteria.  They're just rolling out a [WP7 game engine](http://www.synapsegaming.com/blogs/johnk/archive/2010/11/16/sunburn-2-0-goes-mobile-on-windows-phone-7.aspx/), and they're an official partner of Microsoft too.

[SunBurn XNA Game Engine](http://www.synapsegaming.com/)

Answer (score 1):

www.rpgcreation.com has an engine called Mirage XNA but you need to sign up to the forums to see.

Comment: Looks cool, probably worth a look.